# jQuery.fn.extend function becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I needed a "load" function with caching disabled. To do that I wrote:

FileName: `RootFoolder/script.js`

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    loadWithoutCache: function() {
        var element = $(this);

        if (arguments[0] != undefined) {
            $.ajax({url: arguments[0], cache: false, dataType: "html", success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                element.html(data);
            }});
        }
        else {
            console.log("Invalid Arguments");
        }
    }
});
```

The above works fine when I use it ONCE. However, if I use it a second time, I get `loadWithoutCache` is undefined.

I am using it like below:

Filename:  `RootFolder/index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Loader</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Some Text Description<br /><br />

        <b>Choose a page:</b><br />
        <select id="section">
            <option value="1">Page 1</option>
            <option value="2">Page 2</option>
        </select>

        <div id="content">
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#section').on('change', function() {
                var pages = ["page1.html",
                             "page2.html"];

                var index = $(this).val() - 1;
                $("#content").loadWithoutCache(pages[index]);
            });
        </script>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

FileName: `RootFolder/page1.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <h3>Page 1</h3>
    <b> - Description</b><br /><br />
    <p>
        Some Paragraph
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

FileName: `RootFolder/page2.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <h3>Page 2</h3>
    <b> - Description</b><br /><br />
    <p>
        Some Paragraph
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

On `index` page, if I select `Page 2` from the drop-down, it works. Then I select `Page 1` from the same drop-down, and it gives me undefined.

If I made `loadWithoutCache` a function and then do `$.fn.loadWithoutCache = loadFunc;` right after `var index = $(this).val() - 1;` it will work every time :S

I am just writing this to test how to load an HTML page inside of another page dynamically.

Why is it undefined? What have I missed?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or fiddle that demonstrates the error?

Comment: @Brandon have you verified that $("#content") still finds the "div"?  Also that it only has one match still?  Since you are dropping in HTML I am thinking that there could be an ID conflict introduced.  It is a stretch but if you could post the rendered HTML after the successful "loadWithoutCache" execution it would eliminate it as a possible error.

Comment: @Aliester; @trincot; Hi, I have updated the question to include the pages I am testing with. I can't figure out how to add multiple pages to JSFiddle so instead I added the 3 HTML pages and the 1 Javascript file to the question.

Comment: Ok I have a theory (=.  try this:  "element.html($(data).find('body').html());" instead of what you have now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you switch pages, you load jQuery again, which will nullify your `extend`. You should not load jQuery again. And although you also load *script.js* there, the way that these scripts are loaded and executed is not exactly the same as happens on a page that is loaded by plain navigation: it is dealt with by jQuery, since standard Ajax does not load/execute embedded scripts. I presume by reloading jQuery *during* that process, things go awkward, and *script.js* does not get executed again.

So: leave out the `head` tags from your pages *page1.html*, *page2.html*,.... They are not necessary as you have already the scripts loaded.

Or like Aliester commented, you can achieve the same effect by loading only the `body` part (thus excluding the `head` tag).

Comment: If I don't load it again, it works. But wouldn't it load the `script.js` as also? Which should fix it back?

Comment: I extended my answer to explain that it is not that straightforward.